# Where is the tradeoff between a join with logic (ranges) versus a Join with an intermediate table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Say we have two tables.  One table is a list of ranges, the other is a list of things that fall between those ranges.  We can join based on logic (BETWEEN) or we can generate a table of possible joins, and join on that.  The question is, at what point does it become more expensive to do one versus the other.  Are there any blogs or documentation that can help me figure this out?

In the examples below the data is minimal, but in the actual problem I'm trying to work through each table has millions of records and the intermediate table would have an order of magnitude more.  The goal is to understand the relative computational cost of these two options.

Example Logic Based Join:

```
--Table of Ranges
CREATE TABLE DateRanges (
  ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  StartDate DATE,
  EndDate DATE
)

INSERT INTO DateRanges (StartDate, EndDate) VALUES ('1/1/2023', '1/5/2023')
INSERT INTO DateRanges (StartDate, EndDate) VALUES ('1/3/2023', '1/7/2023') --Overlaps The first
INSERT INTO DateRanges (StartDate, EndDate) VALUES ('2/1/2023', '2/3/2023')

--Table of Things to Join
CREATE TABLE ThingsToJoin (
  ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  ThingDate DATE
)

INSERT INTO ThingsToJoin (ThingDate) VALUES ('1/4/2023')
INSERT INTO ThingsToJoin (ThingDate) VALUES ('2/2/2023')

GO
    
-- Logic Based Join
SELECT
  D.*,
  T.*
FROM
  DateRanges D
INNER JOIN
  ThingsToJoin T
ON
  T.ThingDate BETWEEN D.StartDate AND D.EndDate
```

Example Intermediate Table Based Join:

```
CREATE TABLE IntermediateDates (
  DateRangeID INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES DateRanges(ID),
  DateRangeDate DATE NOT NULL
)
INSERT INTO IntermediateDates (DateRangeID, DateRangeDate) VALUES (1, '1/1/2023')
INSERT INTO IntermediateDates (DateRangeID, DateRangeDate) VALUES (1, '1/2/2023')
INSERT INTO IntermediateDates (DateRangeID, DateRangeDate) VALUES (1, '1/3/2023')
INSERT INTO IntermediateDates (DateRangeID, DateRangeDate) VALUES (1, '1/4/2023')
INSERT INTO IntermediateDates (DateRangeID, DateRangeDate) VALUES (1, '1/5/2023')
INSERT INTO IntermediateDates (DateRangeID, DateRangeDate) VALUES (2, '1/3/2023')
INSERT INTO IntermediateDates (DateRangeID, DateRangeDate) VALUES (2, '1/4/2023')
INSERT INTO IntermediateDates (DateRangeID, DateRangeDate) VALUES (2, '1/5/2023')
INSERT INTO IntermediateDates (DateRangeID, DateRangeDate) VALUES (2, '1/6/2023')
INSERT INTO IntermediateDates (DateRangeID, DateRangeDate) VALUES (2, '1/7/2023')
INSERT INTO IntermediateDates (DateRangeID, DateRangeDate) VALUES (3, '2/1/2023')
INSERT INTO IntermediateDates (DateRangeID, DateRangeDate) VALUES (3, '2/2/2023')
INSERT INTO IntermediateDates (DateRangeID, DateRangeDate) VALUES (3, '2/3/2023')

SELECT
  D.*,
  T.*
FROM
  DateRanges D
INNER JOIN
  IntermediateDates I
ON
  D.ID = I.DateRangeID
INNER JOIN
  ThingsToJoin T
ON
  T.ThingDate = I.DateRangeDate
```

Comment: Have you tried racing your horses in your actual environment and looking at the different plans?

Comment: I would get the execution of both queries to see what's more efficient.

Comment: @larnu Actually generating the intermediate table is a huge overhead and is throwing technical difficulties.  The point of asking this questions is in part to identify if its even useful to go through the process in the first place.

Comment: Theoretically, it is never required to go through the process because the query optimizer is supposed to figure out dynamically whether to spool via a temporary table or scan directly. Realistically, it will fail to do that and you will be seeing bad performance on some data sets, but not on others, and when you upgrade to the new version of SQL Server, the exact details of it being or not being able to figure it out will change. So there won't be a definitive answer.

Comment: Could you explain "why" you need to do this? Especially why are there so many overlapping periods. Maybe whatever you're trying to do don't need range join at all. Also, how many records will DateRanges have and average period length in days and how the day distribution look

Comment: @siggemannen the why has details that could confuse the problem, so I tried to simplify to just query structure.  This is about using linearly referenced coordinates on multiple linear referencing systems and mapping between the two.  e.g. linear asset, landmark1 at 0.1 miles, landmark2 at 0.3 miles, coordinate at 0.3 miles between landmark1 and landmark2; thats being mapped to linear asset offset 0.17 miles.  Is it better to interpolate the coordinate of the landmark based offset or is it better to statically map.  We are talking thousands of linear assets and relatively fine precision.

Comment: You mean you're trying mapping list of accidents along Route 66 which are recorded as list of "length" of the distance travelled along the route? And you want to figure out the actual coordinate of the accident?

Comment: use Intermediate Table Based Join.  this is a common pattern with fiscal year calendars and other date ranges.  index your dates and it will run efficiently. imho.

Comment: I guess I don't understand why you don't do what I would do... generate a shedload of data and test it.  Also, I see that you have ID columns on both tables.  That's probably ok for a PK but, if you're going to do a lot of date lookup work, consider moving the clustered index to the date columnj(s).

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the answer depends very much on the use case, the data and the amount of data you will have in future. So you won't end up with a clear answer here. That's why I recommend that you decide from a strategic point of view:

It is good practice, to keep OLTP use cases as flexible as possible, so use the BETWEEN approach here. But you should try to keep your model as strict as possible to avoid multiple rows when joining with BETWEEN if this is appropriate to your use case (not in your use case obviously).

In an OLAP use case, it is most of the time better to create clean relations by inserting a table where a row for each date exists (CROSS JOIN). The downside of having many rows isn't that relevant in those cases.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, it all depends on your usage.

By using between you can limit your query to the specified date range dynamically. In comparison, the join would pop out every row that contains columns from both tables.

At the end of the day number of rows returned is what's going to determine the cost of bandwidth between the client and the server. So while in development try and test with both and see which one is more fruitful for future cases.

Answer (score 0):

Well, nice question. Agree with other answers that it depends on the use-case, amount of data, etc. Anyway, will try to add several thoughts on this case

First of all the second approach (intermediate table) introduces a bit of "denormalization" in your data structure, what from my point of view is disadvantage, as far as it makes your solution more bug-prone. For example, when you update date of some of ThingsToJoin entities, you have also to update corresponding IntermediateDates entities, and whenever you create-remove ThingsToJoin entity - same action should be performed with IntermediateDates table as well

Second point is concequence of the first one: ThingsToJoin create-update-delete operations would become more time-consuming, as far as they would additionally require manipulations with IntermediateDates table

Thirdly, increased complexity of this solution would result in creating more unit-tests, mainaining exists tests, etc... So time-to-market of your feature would be definitely and significantly increased.

And finally, small test and comparison of execution plans of both queries shows that "intermediate table" variant is also worse:

[image]
[image]

Of course, I performed a very very superficial research with small dataset, but for now this idea does not seem to be promising, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

As many have said, it's on a case-by-case basis. However, if you want to make an informed decision, there are a few factors that you need to take into consideration:

- Relational Algebra: This is the order in which the data is selected. For example, if you join two large tables and then filter, it will be a rather slow process. But if you filter first and then join, it's a quicker process. In your case if you have a large amount of data in both tables it can become problomatic. It is in your case then better to do a conditional search. So conditional search is better for performance compared to a join - but that can be minimized by filtering your tables first then joining them.
- Database Size: Creating an intermediate table allows for references through pointers and avoids duplicate data. In this case an intermediate table will be more storage friendly.

So the tradeoff is really between Processing Speed and Database Size.